# Sum of EditTexts values

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Here I have two EditText widgets (numbers only), and I want to find sum of values from these widgets and put it to TextView.

Here's my **MainActivity.kt**:

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    var resultText = findViewById<android.widget.TextView>(R.id.textView)
    public fun plus(){
        val editText1: Int = findViewById<android.widget.EditText>(R.id.editTextNumber).text.toString().toInt()
        val editText2: Int = findViewById<android.widget.EditText>(R.id.editTextNumber2).text.toString().toInt()
        resultText.setText(editText1 + editText2)
    }
}```
````

Comment: You need a callback for when the EditText text changes. Add a `TextWatcher` to each EditText to accomplish this. Or just add a Button that calls `plus()` when it's clicked.

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
resultText.setText(editText1 + editText2)
```

to this

```
resultText.setText("" + (editText1 + editText2))
```

first line is using `setText(int stringResourceId)`, but you are passing just sum, its not resource id. So convert this sum to `String`, then set to `resultText` using `setText(String text)`

add some `Button` to your layout (`R.layout.activity_main`), attach `OnClickListener` to it (e.g. inside `onCreate`) and call `plus()` method inside `onClick` method of listener

Answer (score 0):

TextView has a method setText() which takes resource Id as int, if you do sum inside setText(), it means you are passing int and there might be a resource not found exception. **You need to pass sum as string to setText()**.

Comment: Not working... Added `.toString` at the end. Now looks so: `resultText.setText((editText1 + editText2).toString())`

Comment: .toString should work. there might be other issues. can you add more about your problem